# How to dump a dictionary that contains user defined class as values using json in python?

Tags: python, json, class, dictionary, dump

I have a dictionary signature2GroupLength2UserDefinedClassDict in python.
First level keys are string.
Second level keys are integer and values are of type user defined class.
How to dump and later on read this dictionary using json in python?

Although I have defined user defined class as follows:

```
#########################################################################
class UserDefinedClass(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__

    def __init__(self, field1, field2, field3):
        self.field1 = field1
        self.field2 = field2
        self.field3 = field3
#########################################################################
```

I still get

```
TypeError: Object of type 'UserDefinedClass' is not JSON serializable
```

when I call

```
print(json.dumps(signature2Length2ProbDict))
```

Comment: can you post your sample `signature2Length2ProbDict` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to specific `JSONEncoder.__init__` signature and 
`json.dumps` signature (which needs to be passed with keyword `cls=` argument to use a custom `JSONEncoder` subclass) you shouldn't combine a custom user class and custom JSON encoder. 
Let them work/live in separate:

```
import json
from json import JSONEncoder

class UserDefinedClass: 
    def __init__(self, field1, field2, field3):
        self.field1 = field1
        self.field2 = field2
        self.field3 = field3

class CustomEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__    


signature2Length2ProbDict = {'a': {1: UserDefinedClass(*['one', 'two', 'three'])},
                             'b': {2: UserDefinedClass(*['four', 'five', 'six'])}}

print(json.dumps(signature2Length2ProbDict, cls=CustomEncoder))
```

The output:

```
{"a": {"1": {"field1": "one", "field2": "two", "field3": "three"}}, "b": {"2": {"field1": "four", "field2": "five", "field3": "six"}}}
```

Comment: Yes, separating them into two separate classes works very well. Thank you very much.